# Constraint component parent on creation

Tags: delphi, components, parent, creation

I want to be able to limit where a component is created.

Like for instance, TMyChild could be a TButton, and TMyParent could be a TPanel,
and when I drop MyChild onto some other component I want MyChild to check if
it is being created in a TMyParent/TPanel or not.

If it is, then fine lets do it, if it is NOT created in a TMyParent/TPanel then cancel
the TMyChild creation and show a message that says something like: "Sorry, MyChild needs to be created in MyParent!".

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must  override the [Controls.TControl.SetParent](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Controls.TControl.SetParent) method.

```
  TMyChild = class(TControl)
  protected
    procedure SetParent(AParent: TWinControl); override;
  end;


procedure TMyChild.SetParent(AParent: TWinControl);
begin
  if (AParent <> nil) then
  begin
    if not (AParent is TMyParent) then
      raise Exception.CreateFmt('Sorry, MyChild needs to be created in MyParent!', [ClassName]);
  end;
  inherited;
end;
```

Comment: This does not _cancel_ or _prevent_ placement. Maybe call inherited afterwards?

Comment: I cant see any cancelation in the code neither.
maybe Destroy; would be a good cancelation?

Comment: @xaid, when the exception is raised the parent property is no set. So the child component is not placed in the Parent component.